# NullReference on Textblock.Text

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I don't understand this. Why am I getting a `NullReferenceException`, when I try to 
change the .Text value of a textblock?

```
private void rt_ValueChanged(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
        {
            var rtslider = (Slider)sender;
            int val = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(rtslider.Value, 0));
            Debug.WriteLine(val);

            if (val <= 1)
            {
                    rt_tb.Text = "A";
            }
            else 
            {
                rt_tb.Text = "B";
            }
        }
```

This is the valueChanged event of a slider.

Comment: Are you sure you have initialized `rt_tb` ? because that seems to be null

Comment: WPF or Silverlight or ??

Comment: This is on WP7 and I dragged the TextBlock in, in Blend.
I can change the value of the textblock in the constructor but not in this method.

Comment: Do you see the value of (val) in output window?

Comment: You haven't said which line you're getting your exception on.  Find that and the answer will most likely be obvious.

Comment: Can you provide a repro?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like, that you dragged a new TextBlock in Blend, but you forgot to rename it. 
Also, you might have a declaration of `TextBlock rt_tb` in code-behind without calling a constructor.

Rename your `TextBlock` in Blend to `rt_tb`, or in Xaml:

```
<TextBlock Name="rt_tb"/>
```

and remove `TextBlock rt_tb` from `.cs` file.